# Regular expression - extract subdomain when domain is unknown

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to use regex to get a subdomain when the domain name is unknown (and could be localhost). So far I have this but it fails the localhost requirement:

```
(.*?)\.(?=[^\/]*\..{2,5})|(?=localhost)

one.domain.com  //matches 'one' which is correct
one.localhost:8000  //no match, expecting 'one'
domain.com  //no match, as expected
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zK3wV5/1)

Comment: if I understood correctly, you want **[this](https://regex101.com/r/zK3wV5/2)**?

Comment: @rock321987 yes except I need a wildcard on the domain name as it could be anything

Comment: @chris85 doesn't match the localhost requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this regular expression, you can obtain the first capturing group to obtain the subdomain:

```
/(.*?)\.(\w+)[\.|\:]([A-Za-z0-9]{3,4})/g
```

Test it:

https://regex101.com/r/rC0lO5/2

All green matches will be subdomains.

### Update:

This updated regular expression will not match `www.domain.com` or `domain.com` as them have not subdomains:

```
/(.*?[^www])\.(\w+)[\.|\:]([A-Za-z0-9]{3,4})/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/rC0lO5/4

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/([^.]+)\.([^.]+\.[^.]+|localhost)(?:[\d]+)?/
```

I would suggest to check in another step whether the matched subdomain equals `www` to keep the regex simple.